# Can i display url Directory name

Tags: php, url, directory, display

Please help.
My site have a error and not found page .If some search
http://example.com/example.
How can i display in my side error page as like this?
"example not found"
Or if anyone search, http://example.com/test
How can i display a  message in my side error page as like this?
"test not found"

Comment: Do you ask about the *design/style* of the page ?

Comment: Can i display url Directory name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the URL **path** with something like this

```
<?php
//http://example.com/example
$path = trim(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH), "/");
echo htmlspecialchars($path) . " not found";
//will output "example not found";
```

and in case you need to extract only the first directory of the path

```
$firstDirectory = explode("/", $path)[0];
```